# How can we find the sums ?

Tags: summation, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

We have the function $$g: [0, 2\pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \\ g(x)=\frac{(x-\pi)^2}{4}, x \in [0, 2\pi]$$

I found that the Fourier series of $g$ is the following:

$$g \sim \frac{\pi^2}{12}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}\cos (kx)$$

Is this correct??

After that, I am asked to find the following sums :

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2} \ \ , \ \ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k^2}$$

How could we find them?? Do we have to use the Fourier series above?? But how??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$\dfrac{(x-\pi)^2}4 = \dfrac{\pi^2}{12} + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\cos(kx)}{k^2} \,\,\,\,\, (\spadesuit)$$
Plug in $x=0$ in $(\spadesuit)$, we then obtain
$$\dfrac{\pi^2}4 = \dfrac{\pi^2}{12} + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac1{k^2} \implies \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac1{k^2} = \dfrac{\pi^2}6$$
Plug in $x=\pi$ in $(\spadesuit)$, we then obtain
$$0 = \dfrac{\pi^2}{12} + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\cos(k\pi)}{k^2} \implies \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^k}{k^2} = -\dfrac{\pi^2}{12}$$

Comment: To have the equality at the relation $(\spadesuit)$ do we have to show the convergence of the series?? Do we have to show that the Fourer series converges to $g$ ??

Comment: Do we have to write the following: 
$$g \text{ is } 2\pi \text{ periodic and since } g \sim \frac{\pi^2}{12}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos (kx)}{k^2} \text{ we have that } g = \frac{\pi^2}{12}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos (kx)}{k^2}$$ ??

Comment: Because g is periodic, continuous and differentiable, its Fourier series converges everywhere to g, so you can use the equal sign.  I don't think you have to prove this fact.  But if you need to, you can use Dini test.